# How to add a UIPageViewController with dynamic width

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

I have 8 viewControllers with a UIPageViewController. I want to have a pageViewController and cildViewControllers with dynamic view widths with padding like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ta3t.png

Can I do this with a UIPageViewController and how can I do this? I know I can do this with just a pageControl and UIViews, but I prefer to do this with childViewControllers.

Comment: did u find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

In the child VC - update your `preferredContentSize` property